# How to get the length of elements in a character vector in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, function, character

Below, I expected that `length(group.name)` would return `3`. But it just returns `1`. Is there a **Base R** solution to get the number of elements of a character vector?

```
group.name = c("bigii, ggigi, ciggi")
length(group.name)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Maybe try this? `lapply(strsplit(group.name,","),length)`?

Comment: @NelsonGon Instead of `lapply`, you can use `lengths(strsplit(group.name, ",")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to count the words with `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(group.name, "\\w+")
#[1] 3
```

---

Or replace all the non-delimiters to blank, use `nchar` to get the number of characters, add 1 (as the delimiter is 1 less than the number of words)

```
nchar(gsub("[^,]+", "", group.name)) + 1
#[1] 3
```

Or using `regexpr`

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\w+", group.name))
#[1] 3
```

It can be turned into a function

```
f1 <- function(stringObj){

  nchar(gsub("[^,]+", "", stringObj)) + 1
 }

f1(group.name)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Just checking, did you get my other question?

Comment: @rnorouzian  I will check it today.  Was a bit busy yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

`group.name` is a single string. I think you are looking to count every word differently separated by comma, you could do that by splitting on comma and then count it's `length`

```
length(strsplit(group.name, ",")[[1]])
#[1] 3
```